# Scrollview contains viewpager and one linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

I tried to make a scrollable view with one `ViewPager` which will take 90% of the screen and then some useful information about images inside the `ViewPager`.

However, when I add the `ScrollView` widget, all sizes and weight doesn't work even if I set `android:fillViewport="true"`. Here's my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            app:popupTheme="?android:attr/homeAsUpIndicator" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="90"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="50dip">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/product_sheet_viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_sheet_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="bbb"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_sheet_color"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Color: Yellow" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_sheet_reference"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Ref: 2049/889/300" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Make NestedScrollView match_parent and add a property fitSystemWindows=true to your NestedScrollView

Comment: @MuhibPirani It throws an Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'fitSystemWindows' in package 'android' even if I add  "compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'" inside gradle script

Comment: @ReazMurshed  Thanks. But the problem is: when I add lots of views after the linear layout that wrapped the viewpager, the viewpager reduce its size. It's like the nestedscrollview has a fixed height and then scroll movement is not supported. However, 90% of the screen has to be covered by the viewpager.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `android:fillViewport="true"` and set the `layout_height` of your `NestedScrollView` to `match_parent`.

So here's the final layout should look like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            app:popupTheme="?android:attr/homeAsUpIndicator" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="90"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="50dip">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/product_sheet_viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_sheet_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="bbb" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_sheet_color"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Color: Yellow" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_sheet_reference"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Ref: 2049/889/300" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is: when I add lots of views after the linear layout that wrapped the viewpager, the viewpager reduce its size.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayoutBottom"
        >
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerPlanDetailBroucher"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnWidth="250dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutBottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"

        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_sheet_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="bbb"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_sheet_color"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/product_sheet_description"
            android:text="Color: Yellow" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_sheet_reference"
            android:layout_below="@+id/product_sheet_color"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Ref: 2049/889/300" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem still persists when I add this good layout inside a ScrollView

Comment: Don't add it inside scroll view, just test it inside another XML file... I have divide relative layout with 90 viewpager